# Power Query Editor - Format Column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I m trying to change column's data type but i m receiving the below error:

`Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type Text`

What i have noticed is that in the specific column is something
strange. In some rows there are data and in others the word "Table".

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreaciated.

Source: .xaf file

UPDATE:
Following @horseyride suggestion, due to the fact that Table are empty, I have used the below formula to convert Table to empty string.

`= if [REf] is table then "" else  [REf]`

Comment: The tables may need to be expanded, have you merged 2 tables together or does this come from an upload?

Comment: This is from the same file, no append or merge took place.

Comment: OK it could be a Column Reference Error, you might be referencing a table when you intended to reference a column within that table,  ie if you are trying to use the values of a column named ColumnName from a table, ensure you're using the correct syntax, like TableName[ColumnName]

Comment: Share all your code. Do you want to ignore the tables?

Comment: @davidebacci i want to chance column type. Almost all rows (there ars more than 200 000 rows) include a value except some rows (app. 2000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the [table] cell to text to make the column all text

If the table has a single cell value in it, you can grab in my example below using add column .. custom column ... with formula

```
= if [REf] is table then [REf][c]{0}  else  [REf]
```

[image]

Alternately, convert all the text to tables with

```
= if [REf] is table then [REf]  else  #table({"REf"},{{[REf]}})
```

[image]

then expand that column

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if [REf] is table then [REf]  else  #table({"REf"},{{[REf]}})),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"REf"}),
ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Removed Columns", "Custom"), each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
#"Expanded" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom",ColumnsToExpand ,ColumnsToExpand )
in Expanded
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. However i tryied the first part but i receive n error that column `c` does not exist. Additionally, trying to mannually expand table i get the warning that `No columns wewre found`

Comment: I am providing an example. You need to use the column names of you own particular columns

Comment: the issue is that 88000 rows out of 90000 shows the REF value as it is should be and the rest indicated as a TABLE. Tryigin to expand the TABLE it shows that there is no columns.

Comment: If all the tables are null, then just replace them with a null . I dont have enough info to help you additionally.  Best of luck